# Are finite projective planes isomorphic to PG(2,q), where q=p^k with p a prime?

Tags: reference-request, plane-geometry

I can't find any reference to the following question:

> Are finite projective planes isomorphic to $PG(2,q)$, where $q=p^k$ with $p$ a prime?

I think it's meaningless to continue studying without reading and understanding this result. I think Hilbert was the first to demonstrate this, but I can't find a reference.

Can anyone help me in this matter? Thanks!

Comment: It's not true, you must have wrong information. You can start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Desarguesian_plane

Comment: it isn't true... there are non-Desarguesian projective planes with 91 points and 91 lines.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes .

Comment: Well, it is true for _certain_ $q=p^k$, such as $q<=8$.

I'd bet my boots it is also true for $k=1$ but this is a huge unsolved problem, not a literature search.

Comment: @gordon-royle: It is widely believed that all finite projective planes have prime-power order but that is not known. Your comment only makes sense under that assumption.

Comment: @Felipe I'm not sure why it needs that assumption; the first part is true because for $q \leq 8$ we know everything and only Desarguesian planes exist. For $k=1$, I was referring to the fact that it is widely conjectured that projective planes of prime order are desarguesian which is independent of whether planes of non-prime-_power_ order exist. 

Comment: @gordon-royle: Phrased this way, it's fine. I just found your original phrasing ambiguous.